# Can buildout create content as part of a Plone install?

Tags: plone, buildout

I'm trying to achieve a repeatable deployment of Plone for a site, and using buildout, basically following Martin Aspeli's book *Professional Plone 4 Development*. I can set up the system with my source products `<site>.policy` and `<site>.theme`, and have activated the theme automatically, but when I run buildout, I still have to instantiate a Plone site and activate the policy product, before creating the standard objects for the site.

Can buildout check for the existence of content objects like the Plone site object or particular folders during setup, and create them if they don't exist with the right settings? Can I do that in a separate `<site>.content` product, or should this be handled in the `<site>.policy`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In principle buildout can do anything you can code, as long as you create a recipe to do the thing for you.

Luckily, someone already created a recipe to create the plone site for you, called [`collective.recipe.plonesite`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.recipe.plonesite):

```
[buildout]
parts = 
    ...
    plonesite

[plonesite]
recipe = collective.recipe.plonesite
site-id = <site>
profiles-initial =
    <site>.policy.profile-default
post-extras =
    ${buildout}/src/<site>.content/site/content/create_content.py
```

The recipe provides several hooks that let you control site creation, and execute system commands before or after the site is created or extra python code before or after GS profiles are run.

In the above example `post-extras` runs a `create_content.py` script with the variables `app` and `site` set:

```
from Products.CMFPlone.utils import _createObjectByType

if 'someobject' not in site:
    _createObjectByType('SomeType', site, 'someobject', title='Foo Bar')
```

Comment: That's really useful! What about the content objects like standard folders, blank pages, etc.?

Comment: @IainHallam: You have two options: create your own python method, or use the (limited) Generic Setup support to create content. I use the former in my projects as it is much more flexible. Run it with `post-extras`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Just for clarification: Can the last line of the buildout.cfg-example also be changed to '${buildout}/src/<site>.content/<site>/content/create_content.py', using the variable twice?

Comment: @IdaEbkes: It's not a variable; the OP used `<site>` in the question, I echoed that, but forgot it that second time. It is a placeholder example name though, buildout only supports `${section:name}` variables.

Comment: If anybody want a fully standard plone 5.1 site, just like if you pressed the 'add plone site' button manually, add these profiles: 
profiles-initial =
    plone.app.caching:default
    plone.app.contenttypes:plone-content
    plonetheme.barceloneta:default